# Creating a matrix using proc iml in sas eg

Tags: sas

When you submit a PROC IML in SAS EG it appends a QUIT statement to the program, this quit statement terminates the procedure and deletes all previously computed matrices.
Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use SAS/IML Studio.  That is the IML version of enterprise guide; it should allow you to connect to a SAS Workspace server, if you're not running in local.

See [Getting Started with the SAS/IML Language](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/144-2013.pdf) by Rick Wicklin (2013 SGF paper) for more details.